# Tmux: missing tmux config file?

Tags: tmux

Just installed tmux via `homebrew` and I'm trying to locate the system-wide tmux configuration file.  The man pages state that the system-wide file should be located in `/etc/tmux.conf`, but for some reason, it is not there.  Where is the default `tmux.conf` file located?

Note: Currently running OSX Mavericks

Answer (score 19):

As far as I can tell the tmux installed via homebrew does not have a system wide conf file. If you did need one you could add your own at `/etc/tmux.conf`. However, I would wonder the need for this. I place my config in `~/.tmux.conf` and everything is very happy.

There is a `/usr/local/Cellar/tmux/1.8/etc` directory but it houses the bash completion scripts. I also checked `usr/local/etc` it it to did not have an installed config.

I'm pretty confident at this point that the tmux installer via homebrew does not install it's own system wide config file instead leaving that as an exercise for the sys admin if such a feature was required.

Answer (score 5):

By default tmux doesn't have a system-wide config that is editable. It's complied into the program.

Use these commands to list out the compiled defaults, then make your own file with it for your user.

```
tmux list-keys         # show current bindings

tmux show-options -s   # show current server options

tmux show-options -g   # show current global session options
tmux show-options      # show current session options

tmux show-options -gw  # show current global window options
tmux show-options -w   # show current window options
```

With tmux 1.7, show-options can also show you the value of a single option (prior versions can only list all the options from the specified class):

```
tmux show-options -gw window-status-format
```

Answer (score 3):

from the `man tmux` page:

```
     -f file       Specify an alternative configuration file.  By default, tmux loads the system configuration file from /usr/local/etc/tmux.conf, if present, then looks for a user configuration file at
                   ~/.tmux.conf.
```

If there is no file, you can just create one using `touch ~/.tmux.conf` and write whatever you want.

Comment: The question was about a system-wide config file.

Answer (score 2):

You should find something useful in:

```
/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples
```

recent versions of tmux only have the examples conf files, it's not an OSX issue, just new default tmux packaging. So you can use any of those doing something like:

```
$cp /usr/share/doc/tmux/examples/someconffile.conf ~/.tmux.conf
```

that should do it.

Comment: Sorry but should not be '~/.tmux.conf' (missing dot ?)

Comment: Is it possible `/usr/share/doc/tmux/examples` was moved?  I do not see it after a recent installation

Comment: @PatrickDougall how did you install tmux?, and which OS?, on linux should be the same and if you use homebrew on OSx sould still be there. But Macports would be different, since tmux files are in /usr/local/Cellar/tmux/xx.version/share/tmux/examples

Comment: @deadPoet I used homebrew on OSX but `ls /usr/share/doc` shows no `tmux` :(

Comment: no big deal though, simple googling show examples :)

Answer (score 0):

[Alon Gouldman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705990/10907864) worked for me. Just to add to it:

I had this issue when working on Ubuntu 20.04.

**Here's how I solved it**:

Firstly, if do not find any configuratio file for tmux in your home directory, then create one inside your **home** (`~`) directory using the command:

```
touch ~/.tmux.conf
```

Next, to make the file to be always available whenever you start a **Tmux** session add the file to either the `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` file. It should be added at the bottom of the file:

```
source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
```

Here's an example:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
```

**Note**: The `~/.bash_profile` file takes the first precedence, then the `~/.bash_login` file as the second precedence, and then the `~/.profile` file as the last precedence.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: How does your answer address the question?

Answer (score -1):

"I will take a crack at it. Here are some solutions off the top of my head. I do not run Mac but I run RH, Debian, FreeBSD, and Solaris, CYgwin and other stuff.

My understanding which is taken straight from `man tmux`. The `-f` flag will specify an alternative configuration file. By default, `tmux` loads the system configuration file from `/etc/tmux.conf`, if present, then looks for a user configuration file at `~/.tmux.conf`. The configuration file is a set of `tmux` commands which are executed in sequence when the server is first started.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unset temporary_array_tmp ; declare -a temporary_array_tmp
temporary_array_tmp=(/etc/tmux.conf ~/.tmux.conf)

# The next line creates an empty global and personal configuration file,
# if it individually does NOT exists.

for i_tmp in "${temporary_array_tmp[@]}" ; do
    [[ ! -f "${i_tmp}" ]] && \
        touch "${i_tmp}" && \
        echo -en "I created an empty tmux configuration file @ ${i_tmp}.  " && \
        echo -e "You need to add configuration settings to ${i_tmp} ." || \
        echo -e "The tmux configuration file ${i_tmp} already exists."
done

# After you add configuration settings, then you need
# to tell tmux to reload the files.

for i_tmp in "${temporary_array_tmp[@]}" ; do
    [[ -f "${i_tmp}" ]] && \
        tmux source-file "${i_tmp}" && \
        echo -e "${i_tmp} The tmux configuration file ${i_tmp} is loaded." || \
        echo -e "The tmux configuration file ${i_tmp} is NOT loaded."
done
unset temporary_array_tmp
```

### Mentionable Notes

Next you can find tmux directories and/or files using `find`. For example:

```
find ~/ /etc /usr -iname *tmux*
```